# What do you say when you want to join a line (queue )

Tags: phrase-usage

Do you say: Who is the last in the line?

As far as I remember I have seen some objections to this phrase on the part of native speakers of English. I don't remember what exactly they didn't like about it but they didn't like something.

Comment: Are you a Spanish speaker?

Comment: I am not Spanish.

Comment: Where are you from if you don't mind me asking? I'm just wondering if people commonly ask who the last in the line is in your country? (see my answer blow!) :)

Comment: I speak Russian.

Comment: интересно! In Russian do you normally ask who's the last in the queue? After you find out, do you have to physically sand in the queue?

Comment: Yes, we always ask "Who is the last?" It's a cliche. In practice, you physically stand in a line, however, people may want to step out of the line for a short time and you must remember which person is in front of you. There are 4 people in the line. Jack is the last person. He has left for 5 minutes. Tim comes and asks. "Who is last?" - He will be answered - "Jack!", even though Jack is out for the time being. The last person is of primary importance in Russian while the location of the end of the line is of secondary importance.

Comment: That's interesting.  In the US, you will usually lose your place in line if you leave, unless you ask someone to hold it for you.

Comment: The English (not the Welsh or Scots or Irish, and *certainly* not Anglophones in general) practically *invented* queuing ([“An Englishman, even if he is alone, forms an orderly queue of one”](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/76091-an-englishman-even-if-he-is-alone-forms-an-orderly)). So we know instinctively who to stand behind without having to ask existing queuers who's currently at the back of the line.

Comment: But it's irrelevant. Even if it's true what you said, however, I have some doubts on that but it's also irrelevant, the English travel and live in different countries where there is a need for asking others to join a queue. I wouldn't compound language and history so closely in this case.

Answer (score 11):

It's more common to talk about the line itself, rather than the people waiting in line. So you can use the following sentence.

> Where is the end of the line?

--OR--

> Could you tell me where the end of the line is?

Comment: I've heard it before. To me it is strange to call a person "the end of the line". But it's just because we say it differently in my first language.

Comment: @user1425 The point is that you're *not* calling a person the end of the line. You're asking for a location (not a person): where the line (of people) ends.

Comment: Well, but a line consists of people, hence, you need a last person in a line. Even if you find the location, you are to stand behind a person not the location. Moreover, sometimes a last person may leave for a while and be out of the line's vicinity for some time. Anyway, that is interesting. It shows how a certain language shapes a certain way of thinking. In my language you must find out who a last person in a line is because the end of the line is a bit abstract notion without the last person of the line.

Comment: *"It's better to talk about the line itself, rather than the people"* - Why? Really, I'd like to know. In Russian, Polish, Czech and probably many more languages there is nothing like that, so if there is some cultural reason behind this, it might be worth telling here.

Comment: @Mołot Basically because it's more common in English and hence it sounds right.

Comment: @MehdiAmiri Thanks for explanation. So shouldn't you replace "better" with "more common" in your answer? For precision's sake?

Comment: @Mołot Asking about the line is impersonal, asking about the person at the end of the line is personal, but you haven't met them before. In this situation it is considered more polite to ask an impersonal question. Your original question could also be asked "Who is last in line?" (without either "the") but "Where is the end of the line?" is definitely the most common way of asking.

Comment: @CJDennis in Slavic languages and cultures there is nothing impolite with this kind of personal. One of the points where language can't really be separated from culture.

Answer (score 8):

In many countries - for example in Spain - a queue at a bank, for instance, won't actually be a physical queue. In order to find out where you are in the queue, you ask people "Are you the last?". Someone will normally point you towards the person who *is* last in the queue. You then check with them. If they are indeed the last person in the queue, you know that you can go up to the counter after that person. At this point *you* become the last in the queue, and if anyone asks who's last, it's you. In the meantime you can wander about or sit down as you please.

In most English speaking countries the system for queuing doesn't work this way. If you aren't physically standing in the queue, you aren't in the queue at all! So if you leave the physical line of people and you don't ask someone to keep your physical place, you aren't in the queue any more and if you want to rejoin the queue, you have to go to the back of the line and start all over again. If you try to reinsert yourself in your old position, you may start an argument with the other queuers. For this reason we don't really have a fixed saying for asking who the last person in the queue is. However, if you just can't physically identify where the end of the physical queue is, you could just ask:

> Are you the last in the queue?

Hope this is helpful.

---

**Postscript**

The Original Poster lives in Russia. The situation in Russian seems to be halfway between the two situations described above. Mostly you stand in the queue, but you can leave the physical line for a little bit. So knowing the 'last in the queue' is very important. This is User1425's comment. I haven't paraphrased it because I don't want to get any details wrong! It's quite interesting:

> [W]e always ask "Who is the last?" It's a cliche. In practice, you physically stand in a line, however, people may want to step out of the line for a short time and you must remember which person is in front of you. There are 4 people in the line. Jack is the last person. He has left for 5 minutes. Tim comes and asks. "Who is last?" - He will be answered - "Jack!", even though Jack is out for the time being. The last person is of primary importance in Russian while the location of the end of the line is of secondary importance.

Comment: This explains a lot about the question!

Comment: This is very interesting.  I had no idea!  I once was waiting in a line in Puerto Rico, and someone asked me in Spanish if I were in the line.  This is typical in the US, when it's not clear whether someone who is standing near a line is actually in it, such as in a grocery store at the deli counter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're pretty close. The issue with that specific sentence is that you're mixing two options. You use "last" in one of two ways here:

Either

> Who is the **last person** in line?

OR

> Who is **last** in line?

You chose to mix the two in a way that is incorrect. Maybe this is why somebody had some objections to your phrase.

In practice, if I want to join the line, I typically look at the line and try to find the person who I think is last. Then I ask them if it's the correct line, and then if they're last. Here's a sample exchange:

> **Person A**: Is this the line for the bathroom? 
>   **Person B**: Yes, this is. 
>   **Person A**: Are you last in line? **OR** Is this the end of the line? 
>   **Person B**: No, I'm not. **OR** No, this isn't. 
>   **Person A**: Where's the end of the line? 
>   **Person B**: It's around the corner. 
>   **Person A**: Okay, thanks!

This is just one sample interaction. But those are the general phrases that I use.

Comment: What confuses me is that in your model (and I think it's a general model of all English speakers) we identify the end of the line with a person. For example - The end of the line is Jack. To me it sounds funny in the least. Another thing. Why do you say "to join the line" but "Are you last in line?" How come you don't use THE in "Are you last in line?"

Comment: Intriguing that you use the word 'line' consistently here. I would have used 'queue', as in 'Where is the end of the queue?'.

Comment: @No'amNewman Interesting! I would never use queue for that sort of thing.  Queue, for me, doesn't apply much to people - but this word seems to vary a lot from region to region. Where did you learn your English?

Comment: @AlexK: I am a native English speaker. The computer concept 'queue' was taken from the natural example of people waiting in a queue. The concept 'stack' comes from dining rooms where plates were kept in a spring loaded stack: clean plates were pushed onto the stack and people would then take those plates. So the plates at the bottom were never touched.

Comment: @user1425: there are two meanings here that you may be mixing. A person who is "in line" has the property of being in line, and they are also (part of) the line. So Jack may be the last person standing "in line" (a property of Jack)  and also the last person "in the line" (description of the nature of the line). Using 'the' is done when talking about the line, and not using 'the' is done when talking about Jack's state of being "in line".

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to enter a line (AmE) or queue (BrE)

If one is **unsure a line exists**, the question

> Is there a line for ...?

can be asked.

When one is unsure **where the line is**, but is sure **there is a line**, one would look any number of people in the vicinity of the *possible* line and ask

> Are you on line?
>   Are you waiting for ...?

Usually if the answer is yes, one would begin to **trace back** to the end of the line possibly asking

> Are you the last in line?
>   Is this the end of the line?

to find where the end of the line is.  Under most circumstances, the end of the line is obvious.

In the cases where there might be **multiple lines forming**, for example in a crowded bus terminal, one might ask

> Is this the line for ...?

to ensure one does not wait in the wrong line.

Usually there is much **gesturing and body language** that goes into informing where the end of the line is, in particular the not uncommon **exasperated glares** from people already waiting trying to ensure their position.

The general question

> Who's the last person in line?

is usually used by the person serving the line to find the end of the line and close the queue.  It can also be used by someone wishing to join the line, but is used usually under duress.

In societies where queueing is a national tradition (read: Britain) the etiquette and rules involved are well known, clear cut, and enforced by the community as a whole.

As a cultural note:

> Brits are taught **to wait** for their turn
>   Americans are taught **to take** their turn

Comment: "to wait their turn" still sounds quite American. "to wait *for* their turn" might be more British-sounding.